# Getting Error in RStudio while loading a package- 'tm'

Tags: r

I've installed the R package `tm`. Now I am trying to load it, but it's giving me this error and warning everytime, I try.

The package is in this location-

```
‘C:/Users/Google/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
```

Error Message--

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘slam’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tm’ was built under R version 3.3.1 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tm’
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you please share the full code, including the suggestions below so that we can see what's going on? It appears to be a missing dependency for `slam` so if installing `slam` doesn't change anything that would be highly surprising.

Comment: Also give your R version and the output from `sessionInfo()`

Comment: I have tried all of the above recommendations - reinstalling latest versions of R and RStudio, installing and loading "pacman" package - and I am still unable to load the "slam" package. I am using R 3.3.1 via RStudio on my MacAir with macOS Sierra v10.12. In this regard, I am getting the following error messages regarding installing and REMOVING "slam" y/n: y
installing the source package ‘slam’ trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/slam_0.1-38.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 49366 bytes (48 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 48 KB *

Comment: update r version to latest, it just worked for me.
to do this, download latest version of R from cran and install it. no uninstall required for previous versions. Cheers!
Manish

Comment: I just make sure all shipping and data information is correct to proceed with the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It worked after I ***reinstalled the R***

.
So I'll suggest to try doing this if anyone facing the same issue. Two of my mates also solved this issue by following the same approach.

Cheers!

Comment: True solution to your problem is not reinstalling R however reading the error message. When you tried to install `tm` you received an error message that `slam` is not known for the R version that you had. The solution is shown [in this excellent post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885408/dependency-slam-is-not-available-when-installing-tm-package). Please note how this question is formatted. You are highly encouraged to follow the same approach as the OP in that latter question.

Comment: I got your point. I'll consider this for sure in answering any question. Thank you. Cheers! :)

Comment: It is more about asking the question than answering but great that you got it.

Answer (score 3):

This is a dependency error. You're just missing one of the packages that `tm` assumes you have.

One solution is to simply directly install that package:

```
install.packages("slam")
```

another is to use a package manager that takes care of this for you:

```
install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(tm)
```

Comment: Still getting the same error message.

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal Can you show the full code and error with the steps above?

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal OP?

Comment: Hey, it worked after I reinstalled the R. Meanwhile, thanks for all your help. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the fact that the 'slam' package currently available on CRAN is dependent on a recent version of R (≥ 3.3.1). 
Updating R will solve the problem.

For those on Ubuntu wishing to keep the R version included in the repository, it is possible to install 'slam' as a package with

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-slam
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone bumps into the page looking for a solution. This one worked for me:

```
install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)
```

Now install an earlier version of slam in case you are using an older version of R.

```
slam_old <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/slam/slam_0.1-37.tar.gz"
install_url(slam_old)
```